# Microsoft Graph Delta Query for User's Photo

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any Delta Query API available in Microsoft Graph for checking if any User has updated their Profile Photo?
I have used the below query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=photo` but response value returns `null` even after the Profile Photo is changed.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to check if any user has updated their Profile Photo.

Based on my test, there are not a API that can do this. So we can submit an new Feature request [on the user voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/).